# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while creating adview

Tags: ios, admob, exc-bad-access, adview

I am trying to create adview with the following code:

```
GADBannerView *adView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
```

but getting an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error

I created `GADBAnnerView` in another project on the storyboard but I need to create it programmatically.

This is the call stack:

```
1   0x108cdef8e StartWebThread()
2   0x104b5faf4 __pthread_once_handler
3   0x104b4ef13 _os_once
4   0x104b5fa93 pthread_once
5   0x107b6185e +[WebView(WebPrivate) enableWebThread]
6   0x107b5e7d6 WebKitInitialize
7   0x102c250a3 ___UIApplicationLoadWebKit_block_invoke
8   0x1047f3614 _dispatch_client_callout
9   0x1047df881 dispatch_once_f
10  0x101b1c4d6 _class_initialize
11  0x101b256e1 lookUpImpOrForward
12  0x101b320d3 objc_msgSend
13  0x10036d4d5 -[GADAdView initWithFrame:]
14  0x10033499f -[GADSlot initWithFrame:]
15  0x100330427 -[GADBannerView commonInitWithAdSize:]
16  0x100330648 -[GADBannerView initWithFrame:adSize:]
17  0x1003308b1 -[GADBannerView initWithAdSize:]
18  0x1003308f1 -[GADBannerView initWithAdSize:origin:]}
```

Comment: The problem was that i didnt perform it on the main thread

Comment: I have corrected the formatting of code block and highlighted the error message in the content. I have also rewritten the title to state your exact problem along with the error. Questions with title that explains the actual problem along with a brief info about the error message are likely to get more attention.